# repmat function in Matlab does not work consistently?

Tags: matlab, graphics2d

Matlab functions meshgrid and streamline are not matching. How to fix?

```
%% direction field plot
[x,y]=meshgrid(-4:.5:4,-4:.5:4);       
dx = 2*x +1*y;
dy = 1*x +2*y;
dxu = dx./sqrt(dx.^2+dy.^2);
dyu = dy./sqrt(dx.^2+dy.^2);
quiver(x,y,dxu,dyu)
hold on  

%% Trajectory Plot
startx = repmat([-4:.5:4], 0,2); 
starty = ones(size(startx));
streamline(x,y,dxu, dyu, startx, starty)
dxu = dx./sqrt(dx.^2+dy.^2);
dyu = dy./sqrt(dx.^2+dy.^2);

print('c:\data\DirectionField','-dmeta')
saveas(gcf, 'c:\data\streamline.emf')
hold off
```

Error messages are given below:

```
Error using repmat!
Replication factors must be a row vector of integers or integer scalars.
```

This has occurred when I added 7 trajectory plots to the code. When using only two trajectories the error did not occur?  What is happening here?

MM

Answer (score 1):

Your `startx` and `starty` matrices are currently empty. The last two arguments of `repmat` should be the number of times you want to repeat the matrix in the vertical and horizontal directions respectively. Since your replication factors are `0` and `2`, the result is an empty matrix. Use positive integers for the replication factors.

I'm not completely sure what you're trying to do, but if you want the `quiver` and `streamline` plots to be consistent, I think you should not be using `repmat` at all. Instead, I think you should just do:

```
streamline(x, y, dxu, dyu, x, y);
```

**Updated after OP's comment:**

If you want to want to plot trajectories from a specific set of starting points, use the code below where `startxy` is an `m x 2` matrix containing the coordinates of `m` starting points.

```
startxy = [0,2;
           1,-3;
           2,1]; %e.g. 3 starting points
streamline(x,y,dxu, dyu, startxy(:,1), startxy(:,2));
```

Comment: I am drawing trajectories onto the direction fields. I want the trajectory to start at  point (0,2). I have 7 points like this which I would like to use as starting values. This code worked for another problem.

Comment: Okay, I see what you mean now. Look at the updated answer.